# Countability of a set of subsequences .

Tags: analysis

Consider a sequence $x_n$ with positive values such that 
$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} x_n $ converges .
Is the set of the subsequences $ x_{k_n}$ of $x_n$ such that 
$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}   x_{k_n} =c \in R$ countable ?
$c$ is previously fixed so the corresponding series of every subsequence converges to the same value.

Comment: I have answered assuming that you mean the set of subsequences such that the corresponding series converges. Do you mean that $c$ is _previoulsy_ fixed instead? That is, your question is that, given $c\in \Bbb R$, the set of subsequences such that $\sum x_{k_n}=c$ is countable?

Comment: Yes I mean that c if previously fixed .So for all the subsequences their corresponding series converges to the same c in $R$

Comment: Then the answer depends clearly on $c$. For example, if $c>\sum x_n$, the set is void. If $c=\sum x_n$ the set is a singleton. For intermediate values, it depends also on the terms of the sequence.

Comment: In both cases the set is  countable .If the answer is no then we need to construct an uncountable set .